# Joomla 3 database query select with limit

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, jdatabase

How can I use this query with joomla 3 with limit to 3

```
SELECT * , (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( $coorlat - latitude) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( $coorlat * pi()/180) * COS(latitude * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( $coorlng - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance
from places
order by distance
```

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with Joomla query building methods and educate yourself on secure query practices.  Start here: https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Secure_on_search then continue reading the many `[mysql]` tagged pages on this site.  You should only  SELECT the columns that you require in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution my code is :

```
$query = "SELECT * , (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( $coorlat - latitude) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( $coorlat * pi()/180) * COS(latitude * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( $coorlng - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance from places order by distance LIMIT 3";
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $db->setQuery($query); 
        $articles = $db->loadObjectList(); 
        foreach($articles as $article) 
        {
            echo $article->title .'<br>';
        }
```

Comment: There are several unadvisable techniques implemented in this answer.  More research is necessary.